# Python program getting stuck on an elif

Tags: python

Fairly new to coding so apologies if this is basic.

I am doing this as a project to pull up useful information quickly whilst flying.  Everything has been working pretty well but I can't get past this.   The program is meant to ask what I want data on.  I would like to be able to type short hand glafail and it will ask which runway then depending on my answer pull up a procedure.  If I ask for glfail however it puts me into the previous elif branch, it asks me 'Which runway? 16 or 34?  When it should ask 'Which runway? 05 or 23?.   I would be grateful of any ideas on where I am going wrong?
regards

```
elif answer == 'efailabz' or answer == 'engfailabz' or answer == 'efailegpd' or answer == 'engoutabz' or answer == 'eturnabz' or 'efail abz' or answer == 'engfail abz' or answer == 'efail egpd' or answer == 'engout abz' or answer == 'eturn abz':
    print('')
    print('')
    print('')
    print('which runway? 16 or 34?')
    orient = input()
    if orient == '16':
        engpop(abdn16)
        main()
    elif orient == '34':
        engpop(abdn34)

elif answer == 'glfail' or answer == 'engfailgla' or answer == 'efailegpf' or answer == 'engoutgla' or answer == 'eturngla' or 'efail gla' or answer == 'engfail gla' or answer == 'efail egpf' or answer == 'engout gla' or answer == 'eturn gla':
    print('')
    print('')
    print('')
    print('which runway? 05 or 23?')
    orient = input()
    if orient == '05':
        engpop(gla05)
        main()
    elif orient == '23':
        engpop(gla23)
        main()
```

Comment: you should not call the main as you have called

Comment: use `answer in ['', '', '']`

Comment: `answer == 'eturngla' or 'efail gla'` will never work for 'efail gla'.

Comment: Thanks all, especially The_spider.  Can't believe I missed that! solved!

Answer (score 0):

As @The_Spider pointed out was the problem within `answer == 'eturngla' or 'efail gla'`.

Here are some pointers for you since you mentioned that you are new to coding:

**You can shorten your if statements. Use the notation pointed out by @azro:**

```
if answer == 'efailabz' or answer == 'engfailabz' or answer == 'efailegpd' or answer == 'engoutabz' or answer == 'eturnabz' or 'efail abz' or answer == 'engfail abz' or answer == 'efail egpd' or answer == 'engout abz' or answer == 'eturn abz':
    # do stuff
```

Can be written like this:

```
if answer in ['efailabz', 'engfailabz', 'efailegpd', 'engoutabz', 'eturnabz', 'efail abz', 'engfail abz', 'efail egpd', 'engout abz', 'eturn abz']:
    # do more readable stuff
```

---

**Avoid using the `main()` function for anything other than to kick off your program**

> Many languages, such as C, C++, Java, and several others, define a
> special function that must be called main() that the operating system
> automatically calls when it executes the compiled program. This
> function is often called the entry point because it is where execution
> enters the program.
>
> By contrast, Python does not have a special function that serves as
> the entry point to a script. You can actually give the entry point
> function in a Python script any name you want!
>
> Although Python does not assign any significance to a function named
> main(), the best practice is to name the entry point function main()
> anyways. That way, any other programmers who read your script
> immediately know that this function is the starting point of the code
> that accomplishes the primary task of the script.
>
> Source: [Defining Main Functions in Python
> (realpython.com)](https://realpython.com/python-main-function/#create-a-function-called-main-to-contain-the-code-you-want-to-run)

---

**Print multiple newlines in one `print()` call**

You can print multiple new lines using `\n`. Like this:

```
print("\n\n\n")
```

This will print 3 new blank lines.